# Retrieving session crashed for unknown reason

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, google-colaboratory

I have the following code trying to profile the layer execution time of a sequential model which consists of three layers conv, pooling and dense. But I noticed running the below code causes the system to crash. I believe this could be due to the RAM issue. I tried to increase the ram and ran the code on GPU still retrieving the same issue.

```
def profiler(model, test_input):
    data_input = test_input
    running_times = []
    for layer in model.layers:
        im_imput = 
        tf.keras.layers.Input(batch_shape=model.get_layer(layer.name).get_input_shape_at(0))
        im_out = layer( im_imput )
        new_model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=im_imput, outputs=im_out )
        start = time.time()
        data_input = new_model.predict(data_input)
        end = time.time() - start
        milliseconds = end * 1000
        running_times.append(milliseconds)
        del new_model
    return running_times

def build_model(input_dim, input_channels, conv_kernel, conv_strides, conv_filters, pool_size, pool_strides, dense_size):
    x = tf.keras.layers.Input((input_dim,input_dim,input_channels))
    conv = tf.keras.layers.Conv2D(kernel_size=(conv_kernel,conv_kernel), strides=(conv_strides,conv_strides), filters = conv_filters, padding="same")(x)
    pool = tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(pool_size,pool_size), strides=(pool_strides,pool_strides), padding="same")(conv)
    flatten = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(pool)
    dense = tf.keras.layers.Dense(dense_size)(flatten)
    model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs=x, outputs=dense)
    return model, flatten.shape.as_list()[-1]

input_dim = 224
input_channels = 3
conv_kernel = "3" 
conv_strides = "1,2"
conv_filters = "64,128,256,512"
pool_size = "2"
pool_strides = "2"
dense_size = "1000"
def process_config(config):
    tokens = config.split(",")
    values = []
    for token in tokens:
        token = token.strip()
        if token.find("-") == -1:
            token = int(token)
            values.append(token)
        else:
            start,end = token.split("-")
            start = int(start.strip())
            end = int(end.strip())
            values = values + list(range(start,end+1))
    return values

conv_kernel_range = process_config(conv_kernel)
conv_strides_range = process_config(conv_strides)
conv_filters_range = process_config(conv_filters)
pool_size_range = process_config(pool_size)
pool_strides_range = process_config(pool_strides)
dense_size_range = process_config(dense_size)

def evaluate_models(conv_kernel_range, conv_strides_range,conv_filters_range,pool_size_range,pool_strides_range,dense_size_range):
    for conv_kernel in conv_kernel_range:
        for conv_strides in conv_strides_range:
            for conv_filters in conv_filters_range:
                for pool_size in pool_size_range:
                    for pool_strides in pool_strides_range:
                        for dense_size in dense_size_range:
                            to_write = open("data.csv", "a+")
                            try:
                                model, dense_input_shape = build_model(conv_kernel, conv_strides, conv_filters, pool_size, pool_strides, dense_size)
                            except:
                                continue
                            random_input = np.random.randn(1,224,224,3)    
                            running_times = profiler(model, random_input)
                            conv_running_time = running_times[1]
                            pool_running_time = running_times[2]
                            dense_running_time = running_times[-1]
                            to_write.write("%d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n" % (conv_kernel,conv_strides,conv_filters,pool_size,pool_strides,dense_input_shape, dense_size,conv_running_time,pool_running_time,dense_running_time))
                            to_write.close()
                            del model
```

Comment: Are the objects which the script is looping over huge? That may be the problem, have you tried unnesting those 6 for loops?

Comment: @EduardoFreireMangabeira, thanks alot I will follow your suggestion really helpful